# leaflet - how to add a handler with cycle behavior?

Tags: javascript, time, leaflet, handler, intervals

I've followed handler tutorial on http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html.

I can do handler that do something on event ('mouseover', etc...) but I don't find a way to do something every 100ms. I have tried to use setTimeout/setInterval but I can't catch 'this' because window object throw the event.

I didn't found something about that in documentation, nor in github. Is there such mecanism in leaflet ?

Anybody could help me ?

Thx

Comment: what would be helpful is to show the code you are having a problem with

Comment: [Create your own event](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#evented) and have it fire every 100 ms; attach a handler to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't catch 'this' because window object throw the event.

Remember to [`bind()` the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to control what `this` will be inside that function, e.g.:

```
setInterval( function(){...}.bind(this), 100);
```

Or if you prefer to do this [the Leaflet way](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#util-bind):

```
setInterval( L.bind( function(){...}, this), 100);
```